# Unexplained behavior of Drupal site after drush cr, between browser and cURL load times

Tags: curl, caching, drupal, drush

After I perform `drush cr` on my Drupal site, I open the site via browser and it takes 52 seconds to load, the first time. But if I perform `drush cr` and then `curl https://example.com` -from within the site's server- and then I open the site via browser, first of all the `curl` returns with the site's HTML after 13 seconds and afterwards loading the site from the browser is instant.

So it is much faster to warm the cache via `curl` first instead of site load via browser. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the structure of Drupal. When you made a request via **cURL** most of process to **build the cache layers** dont't occurs. Before serve the HTML, Drupal builds all its cache layers, that's why the first time of load is so slow.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/caching-to-improve-performance/caching-overview